# Direct Proof of Mathematical Induction Using Well-Ordering Principle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, induction, well-orders

How would one construct a *direct* proof of mathematical induction taking the well-ordering principle as an axiom? I've seen proofs by contradiction, but I'm curious how to do it directly.

Comment: You really have to be careful about the word *direct*. Saying that if there were a countereample, there would be a minimum counterexample seems pretty direct to me. One way to make your question more formal is to ask if the well-ordering principle implies mathematical induction in *intuitionistic* logic, where proof by contradiction doesn't work (in particular, the standard argument shows from the well-ordering principle that the set of counterexamples is *not nonempty,* but that doesn't imply constructively that it's empty, or that for all $n$, the property holds).

Comment: I think appealing to intuitionism is not going to help here. Intuitionistic logic is perfectly happy to start with "Every subset of $\Bbb N$ is either empty or contains a minimal element", prove "Set $X\subset\Bbb N$ contains no minimal element" and conclude "Set $X$ is empty". $A\lor B, \lnot A \vdash B$ is perfectly acceptable in intuitionistic logic.

Comment: @MJD I think you are right, with that statement of the well-ordering principle. However, I was thinking of the well-ordering principle as "for every set $X \subset \mathbb{N}$, if $X$ is not empty, then $X$ contains a minimal element". This version is $\lnot B \to A$, which is intuitionistically weaker than $A \lor B$. And $\lnot B \to A$ together with $\lnot A$ doesn't intuitionistically imply $B$. Would you agree with this analysis?